# Making layout works on all Android devices with fixed dimensions

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am facing trouble of getting my layouts works on all Android devices with the same dimensions. I noticed that every time a friend installs my app, the Buttons and TextViews are changing their initial positions, going up or down some times or making the text inside of it wrapping instead of display it all ( i will attach some code of one of the layouts as an example ). I need some good documentation and/or tutorials for the best layout designs.

**Layout example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dashboardsec"
    tools:context=".main.DashboardActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#009B3232"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="مرحباً بك  "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newsBtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  الاخبار   "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textColorHint="#00AF2B2B"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/formatsBtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  فورمات جاهزة و كتب رسمية"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/storagebtN"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  فيديو  و صور "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exchangeBtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  طلبات استبدال المراكز "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/askBtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  الخرائط و الصرافات الالية "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/phonesBtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  فهرست الهواتف"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/websitsbtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  صفحات تابعة لللجنة"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profilebtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:shadowColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
            android:text="  أدوات مفيدة coming soon"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  السوق  coming soon"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/usersaccount"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  التحكم بالاعضاء"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendimalsBtn"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="  ارسال بريد للادارة"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009B3232"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="   تسجيل خروج "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#DCDFE9"
            android:textSize="22sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: consider using https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: nice , I will spend the night reading that pages , problem is you must have a phone of all sizes screens .

Comment: no, your problem is that you are creating layouts that work for one screen thinking they will work for all screens. constraint layout will help you create some more standard layouts

Comment: please check the photo that i have added , as example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are using fixed size dimensions on your views, and because different phones got different screen sizes you will see this difference.

As mentioned in the comment section- you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to create one layout to support all different screen sizes.

Here is an example of your wanted layout (similar in the look of it any way):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button13"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button14"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button13" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button14" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button17"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button15" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button18"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button16" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button17" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: was suspecting the same , can you edit my xml file so i can compare to the one that i have ? and so will give you the right answer flag .

Comment: All you need to do is go to the XML and change the `Button` tag to any other view that you would like to have. do you want it to look the same as in your question image?

Comment: lammy try it , will replay soon

Comment: it is ok now, I changed all the fixed values to even match parent or wrap content, and now it is ok on 2 defiance phones, thanks.